# How can i find eigenvalue/vector on ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a apps which require eigenvalue/vector of Matrix.My matrix isn't symetric so i can't use Jacobi algorithm...

Comment: Have you looked at the Matrix documentation, such as [`Matrix#eigenvalues`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix/EigenvalueDecomposition.html#method-i-eigenvalues) and related? Or [read articles on calculating the eigenvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Matrix_eigenvalues)?

Comment: Yes, thanks but at my job we use 1.8 and i find the source code but it doesn't work http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/matrix/eigenvalue_decomposition.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of ruby contains the [functions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) you seek.

Consider upgrading to ruby 1.9.3, or getting a copy of matrix.rb from the lastest ruby and importing it into your application.

Comment: Yes, thanks but at my job we use 1.8 and i find the source code but it doesn't work http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/matrix/eigenvalue_decomposition.rb